# Combo setText and getText not working

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am using the org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo with the setText and getText. I am doing the following:

```
System.out.println("Set value = " + model.getType(); //This prints out the type.. i.e. "MyType"
myCombo.setText(model.getType());
System.out.println("myCombo = " + myCombo.getText()); //Prints an empty string
```

I am doing eclipse plugin development and I am instantiating the Combo object in the createControl mathod. If you need more detail, let me know. I just have no idea why the setText is not actually setting the text or the getText is not retrieving the value.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the rest of your code.

Comment: How is your Combo initialized? As per the [Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FCombo.html): _This call is ignored when the receiver is read only and the given string is not in the receiver's list_

Comment: Ahh! That will do it! I had                                      myCombo = new Combo(mainContainer, SWT.READ_ONLY);